# find mean batting average ("Ave") and total number of centuries by country but only including records for which starting year is 2010 or later

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset of cricket players and want to find mean batting average `"Ave"` and total number of centuries `“Hundreds”` by country (column) but only including records for which starting year `“From”` is 2010 or later

`Ave, Hundreds, Country, From` are the columns name

```
new_data.groupby(['Country'])['Ave'].mean()
new_data.groupby(['Country'])['Hundreds']
```

I want to apply these two in a single line and also want to use the condition that `starting Year` should be 2010 or later

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
new_data[new_data['From'].year >= 2010].groupby(['Country'])['Ave'].mean()
```

You can do the same for 'Hundreds'.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have two columns only `Ave` and `Hundreds`. You can do it by using Pandas `.agg` method.

```
grouped_data = new_data[new_data['From'].year >= 2010].groupby(['Country'])
grouped_data.agg(['mean', 'sum'])
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having more columns in dataset but implementation should be for mentioned two

Comment: sorry for late reply, 15 columns were there that is being done now